# Web Part requesting web part manager that is present

Tags: 2013, web-part

I have a SharePoint 2013 publishing site. I have had to insert a web part directly into the master page. I am using Randy Drisgill's publishing starter master page. I have done this with many projects but have never seen / had this error:

**Web Part Manager:You must enable Web Parts by adding a WebPartManager to your page. The **WebPartManager must be placed before any Web Part controls on the page.****

I have checked to see that the web part manager is present in the master page:

```
    *<WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="server"/>*
```

Can any one offer some guidance please?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing reference to web part assembly. Maybe this link will help you:
http://blog.degree.no/2010/12/sharepoint-2010-show-webpart-in-masterpage/